# Why are old job listings being mass-updated and shows as new?

Tags: discussion, support, jobs

Why are old job listings being mass-updated and shows as new? I noticed this this morning, and I know it's happened before.  A bunch (20+) of jobs on the jobs board were timestamped this morning, even though they all appear to actually be older postings.  Do companies have the ability to update the timestamps on their postings?  Or is this a side effect of some sort of system maintenance?

One of the (many) things that sucks about big job boards like Monster and CB is that very few of the "new" listings are actually new — their timestamps are just updated daily, creating an enormous headache for job seekers trying to browse only new listings.  I would hope SO didn't allow this sort of thing on their job board.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Employers have the ability to pay extra for their jobs to be relisted. As you noticed, this is a standard feature on many job listing sites.

I am very sympathetic to the poster's desire to tell which jobs are genuinely new. On the other hand, employers know that older ads get fewer replies (job seekers assume that if the job was listed three weeks ago, it might already have been filled), so they are willing to pay extra to relist their ad to send a signal that, yes, they are still looking.

Over the next few months we're going to redesign the job listing feature and I'll be sure to take this feedback into account to make sure that we design it with a way that regular visitors can see which the genuine new jobs are (or perhaps give you a tool to "hide" an employer that you're just not interested in so that you don't see their ads again).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying how it works.  At a minimum, I think adding a "posted" and "updated" timestamp to the listing would help clear up the confusion.